# Property does not exist on type issue

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I'm using the following code in my first Ionic project:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PapersProvider } from '../../providers/papers/papers';

/**
 * Generated class for the LoadPaperPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-load-paper',
  templateUrl: 'load-paper.html',
})
export class LoadPaperPage {

  public paper = {};
    public questions = {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public papersData:PapersProvider) {
    // let paperid = navParams.data.paper;
    this.paper      = this.navParams.get('paper');
    this.questions  = this.navParams.get('questions');
    this.questions  = this.questions.questions;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }
}
```

The code works fine when testing my **load-paper** page. However, when I have to re-serve the project and it's starting from the beginning (splash screen etc), I get the following error:

> Typescript Error
>       Property 'questions' does not exist on type '{}' src/pages/load-paper/load-paper.ts

```
this.questions  = this.navParams.get('questions');
this.questions  = this.questions.questions;
```

The data I'm assigning to `this.questions` doesn't exist at the point when the splash screen is loading so I understand that it fails as a result but I've tried testing:

`if(this.questions.questions !== 'undefined')`

and:

`if(this.questions.questions)`

unsuccessfully.

Comment: Create an interface for your questions object which will hold questions property and then make your questions object implement that interface.

Comment: Hi Sisko. There's  no need to add "please help" material to every single one of your questions - readers know you want help, and they don't want to see you pleading. If you can keep your questions succinct, it saves on editing effort, and the appearance of [asking confident questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) may garner you a somewhat better reception in general too.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the warning to go away, you should be able to do `this.questions  = this.questions['questions'];`

However, I would highly suggest creating a proper interface to make sure you handle your data correctly.